# Find values C that exists in every B from A

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 fields ID,A,B.
I want to find every B that occurs in every A from some ID

For example:

```
ID  |   A   |   B   |
----------------------
1   |   10  |   22  |
1   |   10  |   24  |
1   |   11  |   22  |
    |       |       |
2   |   12  |   31  |
2   |   13  |   33  |
    |       |       |
3   |   14  |   34  |
```

Should return:

```
ID  |   B   |
-------------
1   |   22  |
3   |   34  |
```

because for every different value of A from ID 1 , B = 22 occurs.
Same for id 3.

Any idea how I can do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Im not sure if you description is OK or your sample is wrong, but `B=24` doesnt occure on every value of `A`. first row is 22,

Comment: That's why it only returns 22 for id=1 and not 24.

Answer (score 1):

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd317/17)**

You can use this query to validate what rows your need.

```
SELECT T1.B, T1.ID, COUNT(DISTINCT A), T2.total_id_a
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN (SELECT ID , COUNT(DISTINCT A) as total_id_a
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY ID) T2
  ON T1.ID = T2.ID
GROUP BY B, ID;
```

But this will provide the result you want.

```
SELECT ID, B 
FROM (
      SELECT T1.ID, T1.B, COUNT(DISTINCT A), T2.total_id_a
      FROM Table1 T1
      JOIN (SELECT ID , COUNT(DISTINCT A) as total_id_a
            FROM Table1
            GROUP BY ID) T2
        ON T1.ID = T2.ID
      GROUP BY B, ID
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT A) = T2.total_id_a
     ) T
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID |  B |
|----|----|
|  1 | 22 |
|  3 | 34 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# For case ID=1 and B=22 for example above
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.B 
FROM yourtable AS t1
INNER JOIN yourtable AS t2 
     ON t2.B = t1.B 
    AND t2.A <> t1.A 
    AND t1.ID = t2.ID

UNION

# For case ID=3 and B=34 for example above
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.B 
FROM yourtable AS t1
INNER JOIN yourtable AS t2 
     ON t2.B = t1.B 
    AND t2.A = t1.A 
    AND t1.ID = t2.ID
LEFT JOIN yourtable AS t3
     ON t3.ID = t1.ID
    AND (t3.A <> t1.A OR t3.B <> t1.B)
WHERE t3.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: It is returning "empty set",  even for ids with only one entry in the table (one A and one B).

Comment: Hmmm. Then I dont understand description

Comment: I know my explanation is kind of confusing.
Basicaly i want to find every B that is in every A from an ID.
If A is a user's folder and B a user's file, I want to find every file that
is in every folder from an user

Comment: Edited for example with id=3. But I really dont understand exactly what your need

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try to solve it from your example